# Filter by attribute value in Orion Context Broker SQL Style - "Attribute" LIKE '%text%'

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Following [NGSIv2 specification document](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) is there any way to search entities by part of attribute string value?

Something like 
http://192.168.36.95:1026/v2/entities?type=POI&options=keyValues&q=Description=='*PART OF TEXT*'
 to get entities that Description attribute contains 'PART OF TEXT'

Answer (score 2):

you can use the match pattern operator. see below

~=. The value matches a given pattern, expressed as a regular expression, e.g. color~=ow. For an entity to match, it must contain the target property (color) and the target property value must match the string in the right-hand side, 'ow' in this example (brown and yellow would match, black and white would not). This operation is only valid for target properties of type string.

so in your case it would be

http://192.168.36.95:1026/v2/entities?type=POI&options=keyValues&q=Description~=

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply REGEXP matching to ID NGSI field:

> You can filter using entity id patterns, using the idPattern URL
>   parameter (whose value is a regular expression). For example, to get
>   all entities whose id starts with Room and is followed by a number in
>   the 2 to 5 range (in this case retrieving Room2) you can use (note the
>   -g in curl command line to avoid problems with brackets): curl localhost:1026/v2/entities?idPattern=^Room[2-5] -g -s -S -H 'Accept:
>   application/json' | python -mjson.tool
>
> found at:
>   https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#getting-all-entities-and-filtering

I'm not sure if this apply also to NGSI Type. But this functionality doesn't apply to user defined attributes.